# Want to travel to US on B1/B2 visa with wife

Tags: b1-b2-visas

I am an Indian citizen and planning to travel to US on B1/B2 visa to attend a technical conference.  My trips are paid by my employer.  I want to take my wife also on this trip on B2 visa.  I will be covering her expenses.  We both are going to attend interview in some days.

My question is what are the documents required for my wife?

Comment: B2 visa and the standard documents required.

Comment: Your wife is not your sponsor here. I have edited that out of the question.

Comment: Your wife needs her own visa, she cannot travel on yours. Her application needs to be complete inandof itself.

Comment: Thanks for reply...I want to know the list of documents and suggestion for interview.

Answer (score 1):

All applications for the [B1/B2 visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html) require the same process and documentation:

> **Gather Required Documentation**
>
> Gather and prepare the following required documents before your visa interview:
>
> - **Passport** valid for travel to the United States – Your passport must be valid for at least six months beyond your period of stay in the United States (unless exempt by country-specific agreements). Each individual who needs a visa must submit a separate application, including any family members listed in your passport.
> - **Nonimmigrant Visa Application, [Form DS-160](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html#ds160) confirmation page.**
> - **Application fee payment receipt**, if you are required to pay before your interview.
> - **Photo** – You will upload your photo while completing the online Form DS-160. If the photo upload fails, you must bring one printed photo in the format explained in the [Photograph Requirements](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/photos.html).
>
> **Additional Documentation May Be Required**
>
> Review the instructions for how to apply for a visa on the website of the U.S. Embassy or Consulate where you will apply. Additional documents may be requested to establish if you are qualified. For example, additional requested documents may include evidence of:
>
> - The purpose of your trip,
> - Your intent to depart the United States after your trip, and/or
> - Your ability to pay all costs of the trip.
>
> Evidence of your employment and/or your family ties may be sufficient to show the purpose of your trip and your intent to return to your home country. If you cannot cover all the costs for your trip, you may show evidence that another person will cover some or all costs for your trip.
>
> **Note**: Visa applicants must qualify on the basis of the applicant's residence and ties abroad, rather than assurances from U.S. family and friends. A letter of invitation or Affidavit of Support is not needed to apply for a visitor visa. If you choose to bring a letter of invitation or Affidavit of Support to your interview, please remember it is not one of the factors used in determining whether to issue or deny the visa.